# Query on rest service

Tags: rest

I am newbie to rest services.I just want to know the difference between the Http request returning JSON object is it same as rest service. Because it also does the same.. So what is difference between HTTP returning JSON and REST

Answer (score 1):

REST isn't about JSON, although web services having JSON serialization and RESTful services gained popularity in tandem.

REST has it's principles on Resources and uses HTTP verbs and status codes to handle CRUD operations on the resource. There are, of course various Maturity levels of as proposed by Leonard Richardson. Martin Fowler has an [article about it](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).

You can have RESTful services without JSON as the format, and have http services returning JSON, but not being RESTful. One does not imply other.

**Update:**

[Although this could be a different question, here is my view on the question asked]

Q: I use Spring MVC and I annotate a method with `@responsebody` when I need JSON output or RESTful endpoint. How does it work?

A: `@responsebody` has nothing to do with either. It just writes the method return value directly to the Http Response. No model binding or view binding is done. Refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody).

My guess is that since you are using an MVC framework, your endpoints tend to be RESTful, since the endpoints are resource centric, the Model being the resource here. 
And while I haven't seen your code, my guess is that the method you are annotating with `@responsebody` returns a raw json which is sent back.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have a question. I am working on spring MVC . If I need JSON object i am adding @responsebody annotation and even if i want to make it restful service again I have to add same annotation. Do you have any Idea how it REST?

Comment: This could be a different question, but have updated my thoughts here.